# How to add a custom button or link beside a form field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django with crispy_forms third party library. I want to add a link beside a form field like some forms in Django admin app. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've picked quite a complicated example that uses a method I wouldn't even recommend. But I'll try to explain how you see what you're seeing, and keep it short.

That is a `AdminTimeWidget(forms.TimeInput)` and a `AdminDateWidget` both nested in a `AdminSplitDateTime(SplitDateTimeWidget(MultiWidget))`. The `MultiWidget` part of this isn't really important, that's just how you bind two widgets together to provide one value (a `datetime.datetime`).

Here's what `AdminTimeWidget` looks like:

```
class AdminTimeWidget(forms.TimeInput):
    @property
    def media(self):
        extra = '' if settings.DEBUG else '.min'
        js = [
            'vendor/jquery/jquery%s.js' % extra,
            'jquery.init.js',
            'calendar.js',
            'admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js',
        ]
        return forms.Media(js=["admin/js/%s" % path for path in js])

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        final_attrs = {'class': 'vTimeField', 'size': '8'}
        if attrs is not None:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)
super().__init__(attrs=final_attrs, format=format)
```

That adds a [`DateTimeShortcuts.js`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/385cf7091e066604f9e417c6ef63685492a08d13/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L38) script to the page (in the way that Admin Widgets can, via the [form media property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/media/)) and it's that script that iterates input tags looking for date and time inputs.

There's a LOT of machinery involved to get that happening but again, in effect, it's just a bit of javascript that looks for a date/time input and adds the HTML client-side.

## But you probably don't want to do that.

As I said, that's a *very* complicated widget, and in Admin where it's harder to alter things on the fly. If you want to write an Admin widget, you probably *do* want to go that way.

But if you already control the template, or a crispy layout, you could just bung in some HTML. Crispy has an `HTML` element that you can throw into layouts. This is [well documented](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html).

Or if you want a reusable widget, you could use a custom template. Since Django 1.11, Widgets use templates to render.

1. Create a widget, borrowing from an existing one to save time

   ```
   from django.forms import widgets

   class DateWithButtonWidget(widgets.DateInput):
       template_name = 'widgets/date_with_button.html'
   ```
2. Customise the template with the HTML you want:

   ```
   {% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %} <button>MY BUTTON</button>
   ```
3. Use that widget in your form:

   ```
   class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
       fancydate = forms.DateField(widget=DateWithButtonWidget)
   ```

Of course, wiring that button to *do* something is all up to you. Using a fully-scripted option might be what you need after all.

Comment: This worked but the button is displayed on the next line, not inline...How do I do this? @Oli